# How to show value on one textview if their id is same in JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, api, listview

I have json data that are showing a hotel previous order detail.

I want if date & time are same then "name" of the items should set in same TextView in the ListView with comma(,) separated.

The data I'm getting from **API**  is this:-

```
{
 "error": false,
 "checkstatus": [
[
  {        
    "id": "244",                  
    "name": "Chicken Breast Curry",
    "date": "2020-02-22 11:13:53"       
  },
  {        
    "id": "244",       
    "name": "Vegetarian ", 
    "date": "2020-02-22 11:13:53"       
  },      
]
[
  {        
    "id": "245",                  
    "name": "Punjabi Royal for 2 person", 
    "date": "2020-02-25 09:11:23"       
  },       
]
]
}
```

**This is my Java Class:-**

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = array.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                sproduct_name = object.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);                  
                sdate_time = object.getString(TAG_TIME);                   
                orderId = object.getString(TAG_ORDER_ID);

                get = new HashMap<>();
                get.put(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, sproduct_name);                    
                get.put(TAG_TIME, sdate_time);                   
                get.put(TAG_ORDER_ID, orderId);

                myList.add(get);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), myList, R.layout.order_history_child,
            new String[]{TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, TAG_TIME, TAG_ORDER_ID},
            new int[]{R.id.product_name, R.id.date_time, R.id.order_ids}) {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView product_name = view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);              
            TextView date_time = view.findViewById(R.id.date_time);               
            final TextView orderid = view.findViewById(R.id.order_ids);            

            return view;
        }
    };
```

Now I am getting data like this **screenshot**:-

[image]

**This is what I Want**:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ArrayList for Date & Time and String Builder

```
List<String> datetimeList = new ArrayList<String>();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Add the String of Date & Time in your ArrayList and compare with list, if String is already exists or not

```
 for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    sdate_time = object.getString(TAG_TIME);                   
                    orderId = object.getString(TAG_ORDER_ID);

datetimeList.add(sdate_time);

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String input = input.next();
boolean isExist = false;
for (String item : datetimeList) { 
    if (input.equals(datetimeList.get(counter))) {
        //Your logic if it's there.
         isExist = true;
         break;
   }
}

 if(isExist) {
     //Found in the arraylist.
     sproduct_name = object.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);                  

    sb.append(sproduct_name);



 get = new HashMap<>();
                get.put(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, sb.toString());                    
                get.put(TAG_TIME, sdate_time);                   
                get.put(TAG_ORDER_ID, orderId);

            myList.add(get);

 }
else{
         sproduct_name = object.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME); 
  get = new HashMap<>();
                get.put(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, sproduct_name);                    
                get.put(TAG_TIME, sdate_time);                   
                get.put(TAG_ORDER_ID, orderId);





  myList.add(get);                 

}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, but please tell me how i can remove duplicate row in the ListView.

Comment: @AmitSharma  If you don't want to allow duplicate into the collection of your object then use the Set object before setting to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = array.getJSONArray(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                sproduct_name = object.getString(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);                  
                sdate_time = object.getString(TAG_TIME);                   
                orderId = object.getString(TAG_ORDER_ID);

                get = new HashMap<>();
                get.put(TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, sproduct_name);  

                 //check here
                if(!object.getString(TAG_TIME).equals(sdate_time)){
                       get.put(TAG_TIME, sdate_time);                   
                }

                get.put(TAG_ORDER_ID, orderId);
                myList.add(get)

            }
```

Comment: Plz explain it, i implemented your code but i am not able to get result as per my requirement.